# Java instanceOf analogue in Javassist

Tags: java, android, javassist

I'm working on a plugin for **Gradle** in android project. I use **Transformation Api** for manipulate with byte code across compilation and for this purpose I choosen **Javassist**. My question related to this library. Before manipulate byte code I need determine which type has this class. For example, if some `ctClass` has method `setOnClickListener()`, I want to know its type (type of class which represented by CtClass). May be `ctClass.instanceOf(android.view.View)` or `ctClass.instanceOf(android.view.ViewGroup)`. I found method `.toClass()` but it throws `InvocationTargetException` and I think it does unnecessary  work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CtClass` object is usually obtained using ClassPool.get("classname") and represented the class file of the class you selected to get through the "classname". It basically represents the object itself, not an instance of that object.

Therefore it is not an instantiated object and finding out which "instance" it is does not make sense.

However if you need information about the class hierarchy you can use a lot of methods exposed by the `CtClass`. Here just a couple of examples:

- [`getSuperclass()`](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/CtClass.html#getSuperclass()) - obtains the class object representing the superclass of the class
- [`getInterfaces()`](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/CtClass.html#getInterfaces()) - obtains the class objects representing the interfaces implemented by the class